# Possible to retrieve value of instance which singleton class is attached to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a example of singleton class:

```
class MyPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end

post = MyPost.new(:title => 'post title')

def post.some_method
  #is it possible to retrieve value of `post`?
  my_post_title = post.title #???. Not working now
end
```

Is it possible to refer back to `post` in `def post.some_method`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors: 
1. unending single quote in the title.
2. when you are inside the `post` then you can access directly @title, you cannot call it `post.title`

```
class MyPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end

post = MyPost.new(:title => 'post title')

def post.some_method
  my_post_title = @title
end

post.some_method
```

or if you have set your attr_accessor for your `title`

```
require 'active_record'

class MyPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end

post = MyPost.new(:title => 'post title')

def post.some_method
  my_post_title = title
end
```

Comment: The downvoter can you specify whats wrong with program?

Comment: `title` returns `nil` in debug.

Comment: I have two ways of doing it.. please see which one works for you

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Inside a method, the special variable `self` holds a reference to the receiver of the message:

```
class MyPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end

post = MyPost.new(title: 'post title')

def post.some_method
  my_post_title = title
end
```

Comment: This errors out since. title is not a constant or not defined in the scope

Comment: If that is the case, then the OP's question doesn't make sense. The OP's code assumes that he can call a method named `title` on the object referenced by the variable `post`. My answer merely makes the exact same assumptions as the OP's question does. The OP's question is solely about how to get a reference to the object, it is not about how to define a method named `title`. I'm assuming the OP already knows how to define methods.

Comment: No, I haven't. I won't install Rails just to test one line of code. I have, however, tested an equivalent piece of code that shows that my solution works under the assumptions made in the OP's code, namely that there exists a method `title` whose implementation is missing from the question. Maybe, the model has a `title` column in the database, maybe the method is defined in another file, I don't know. All I know is: the method exists in the question, therefore I can also assume that it exists in the answer. Again: the question is *not* about how to define a method named `title`, that method …

Comment: … is already assumed to exist by the code in the OP's question. The question is about how to get a reference to the receiver in a singleton method.

Comment: well, thats why I used @title in my answer

Comment: I do see `self` returns `#<Class:#<PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest:0x0000000ca6d4a0>>` which is the instance. However how can I retrieve the value of field such as `id`? Type `id` in debug returns `undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x0000000b391b00>`

Comment: Under `self.columns` there are names of the attributes. But I did not find the value of the attribute.